# CI how to oder_by using just the last 4 character of the data

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
+-----+----------+
| PID |   Number |
+-----+----------+
|   1 | 1.3.0001 |
|   2 | 1.3.0002 |
|   3 | 1.1.0003 |
|   4 | 1.2.0004 |
+-----+----------+
```

I have the table above, now how do I run the query order_by just the last 4 digit of the number ? If I run the query above with order by Number DESC, the result will be 1.3.0001, 1.3.0002, 1.2.0004, 1.1.0003, I want it to be ordered by just the last 4 digits so it should be 1.2.0004, 1.1.0003, 1.3.0002, 1.3.0001

PS: For a lot of reasons I cannot use order by PID or any other columns, I need to specifically order by column Number.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should work, cant test it as i dont have your data

```
ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(number, '.', 2);
```

Or as @nogad has has said you can simplyfy this to order by a substring and include start position as the second parameter

```
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(number, 4)
```

Comment: or `order by SUBSTRING(number, 4)`

Comment: the SUBSTRING(number, 4) is exactly what I'm looking for ! Thanks a lot.. Could you care to explain it a little bit though on why is it 4 and not -4 for the SUBSTRING ?

Comment: @nogad you may as well post your comment as an answer

Comment: Depending on your data pattern, `SUBSTRING(number, 4)` might not work, for example when your data is '999.1.1234'.  If you know the pattern is 'xxx.yyy.zzz' and you want to get the zzz part then `SUBSTRING_INDEX(number, '.', 2)` is safest.  Alternately, if you know the last four digits are always 4 characters, you can use `RIGHT(number, 4)`.  The solution depends on how confident you are of your string pattern